# Exporting or Saving CX509PrivateKey

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

Is it possible somehow to save or export `CX509PrivateKey`. The idea is that I create a CSR sent to CA get a Certificate and then... somehow I have to get the private key but no idea how, unfortunately nothing found on google.

My piece of code:

```
var objPrivateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
objPrivateKey.Length = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["objPrivateKeyLength"]);
objPrivateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE;
objPrivateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_ALL_USAGES;
objPrivateKey.MachineContext = false;
objPrivateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG;
objPrivateKey.CspInformations = objCSPs;
objPrivateKey.Create();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also see [help/tagging].

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not sure that's the full consensus, though (see [this question too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292281/372643)). While C# isn't particularly useful here, it's useful to have some idea of the environment in the title (e.g. .Net or Java), not just the class name that could belong to both (which is the case for `X509Certificate`).

Comment: @Bruno: sorry, disagree. [tag:.net] is useful  in the tags, maybe (I added it there), but are you truly suggesting that every question about .NET should have the word ".NET" in the title? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, especially the section "Should I use tags in titles?"

Comment: @JohnSaunders, not necessarily, but as someone who typically monitors a tag that overlaps multiple platforms (`ssl`), it is useful to know straight away from the title what it's about. We encourage good and clear writing styles, this starts with a descriptive title. There are questions about `X509Certificate` on both .NET and Java, yet they're generally very different (different content, different audiences). If I walked into a library and found a book called "*Cooking methods in [ancient] Rome*" without the word "ancient", just because it's in the history section, I'd find that very odd.

Comment: @Bruno: the help center topic I pointed you to is official. It's past the "consensus" stage. And I recommend you learn to look at the other tags to determine the platform, and edit the question to use a platform tag if it is not present. "Data" belongs in the titles. "Metadata" belongs in the tags.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, agreed, as a pseudo-tag (as it was), it's not great, but as part of the sentence, it would work very well, e.g. "*Exporting or Saving CX509PrivateKey using the standard .NET API*" (or "*... in C#*"), otherwise, you have to know the field quite well to know which platforms `CX509PrivateKey` may belong to.

Comment: @Bruno: or, I could add the [tag:.net] tag, which is what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I have solved this task in this way. (Here is a bit more code, so you can understand what I was trying to do).

Here all the job is done.

```
/*
    using CERTADMINLib;
    using CERTCLILib;
    using CertSevAPI.Core.Models;
    using CertSrvAPI.Core;
    using CertSrvAPI.Core.Models;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Prng;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
    using System;
*/

var caService = new CAService();

// Create a certificate request.
// The private key is here.
var caRequest = caService.CertRequest(subjectDN);

// Submit the certificate request and get the response.
var caResponse = caService.SendCertRequest(caRequest.Request);

// If certificated is not issued return null.
if (!caService.IsIssued(caResponse.Disposition))
{
    return null;
}

// Download the P7B file from CA.
var p7b = new WebClient().DownloadData(
    _appSettings.CERT_SRV + "/CertSrv/CertNew.p7b?ReqID=" + caResponse.CertRequest.GetRequestId() + "&Enc=bin");

try
{
    var certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    
    // Import the downloaded file.
    certCollection.Import(p7b);

    // Create a PKCS store.
    var pfx = new Pkcs12Store();
    
    // Insert root CA certificate into the PKCS store.
    pfx.SetCertificateEntry("rootCert",
        new X509CertificateEntry(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certCollection[0])));

    // Get the second certificate from the downloaded file.
    // That one is the generated certificate for our request.
    var certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry[1];
    certificateEntry[0] = new X509CertificateEntry(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certCollection[1]));
    
    // Insert our certificate with the private key
    // under the same alias so then we know that this private key
    // is for our certificate.
    pfx.SetKeyEntry("taxkey", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(caRequest.PrivateKey), certificateEntry);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    
    // Stream PFX store using the desired password
    // for our file.
    pfx.Save(memoryStream, password.ToCharArray(), new SecureRandom());
   
    var pfxBytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
    pfxBytes = Pkcs12Utilities.ConvertToDefiniteLength(pfxBytes, password.ToCharArray());

    // Here you can save the pfxBytes to a file, if you want.
    // Actually I needed it to give as a response in MVC application.
    return File(pfxBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "NewCert.pfx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // If there is an error remove private key from
    // the memory.
    caRequest.PrivateKey = null;
    caRequest.Request = null;

    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);

    if (showError != null && showError.ToLower() == "true")
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The private key is in the `CARequest`.

```
/*
    using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
*/

public class CARequestModel
{
    public AsymmetricKeyParameter PrivateKey { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
}
```

The private key is saved in the memory until the moment we need it to save to the PFX file, and it is generated at the moment we create the certificate request. So here is the certificate request generating method.

```
public CARequestModel CertRequest(string subjectDN)
{
    var name = new X509Name(subjectDN);
    var rsaKeyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    
    rsaKeyPairGenerator.Init(
        new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(
                new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), _appSettings.PRIVATE_KEY_LENGHT));

    // Generate key pair.
    var keyPair = rsaKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
    
    // Get the private key.
    var privateKey = keyPair.Private;
    
    // Get the public key.
    var publicKey = keyPair.Public;

    // Set the key usage scope.
    var keyUsage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature);
    var extensionsGenerator = new X509ExtensionsGenerator();

    extensionsGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, keyUsage);

    var attribute = new AttributeX509(
        PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtExtensionRequest, new DerSet(extensionsGenerator.Generate()));

    // Create the certificate request
    var csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest("SHA256withRSA", name, publicKey, new DerSet(attribute), privateKey);
    
    // Get it as DER, because then I have to submit it to the MS CA server.
    var csrBytes = csr.GetDerEncoded();

    // Return the Request and private key
    return
        new CARequestModel
        {
            Request = Convert.ToBase64String(csrBytes),
            PrivateKey = privateKey
        };
}
```