# Export Private Key And Certificate to PFX

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, bouncycastle, x509certificate2

I have the `privateKey` string and `X509Certificate2Collection` with the root 
 certificate and certificate. Is there any way I can export all of these at once to a PFX file?

My code:

```
var p7b = new WebClient().DownloadData(
          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certSrv"] + "/CertSrv/CertNew.p7b?ReqID=" +
          caResponse.CertRequest.GetRequestId() + "&Enc=bin");

var certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certCollection.Import(p7b);

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
var pemWriter = new PemWriter(streamWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(caRequest.PrivateKey);
streamWriter.Flush();

var output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer()).Trim();
var index_of_footer = output.IndexOf("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
memoryStream.Close();
streamWriter.Close();

var key = output.Substring(0, index_of_footer + 29);
var pfx = certCollection.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, password);
```

In my code I export just the certificates I own.

Comment: Since you tagged bouncycastle, have you looked at the Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs namespace (pfx is essentially a PKCS#12 store)?

Comment: Ow... yes of course! And I managed to solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: That was quick! Consider adding and accepting an answer yourself, including some of the code that solved your problem.

Comment: Here is the answer to my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039639/exporting-or-saving-cx509privatekey/33596494#33596494

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting or Saving CX509PrivateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039639/exporting-or-saving-cx509privatekey)